# Запрос SELECT в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE wage > 100 AND people =
```

Вопрос, что мне написать после `people =`(знака равно), чтобы было эквивалентно всем значениям в столбце people?

Comment: По вашему вопрос не угадать, что вы спрашиваете! Переформулируй свой вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE wage > 100 AND people = people
```

Comment: А можно как с оператором like '%', но только с оператором сравнения = '%'?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE wage > 100 AND people = '%'

Comment: Для этого нужно использовать LIKE, а не "=".

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не нужно писать. Просто удалите лишнее условие.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE wage > 100
```

Comment: ))) Нужно с этим условием, но чтобы было равнозначно всем значениям из столбца people, есть варианты?

Comment: @Влад, а зачем? На результат запроса это никак не повлияет.

Comment: В people будет приходить значение переменной. Нужно чтобы в нужном случае туда приходила строка, эквивалента всем значениям.

Comment: Так переменная или просто SQL, вы уточняйте что вы хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: Возможно создать такого плана запрос: SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE wage > 100 AND people = '%'